Mathematical definition of a wave
I am aware that, in general, a wave is a type of energy transfer (though I admit I don't know if there are more complicated types of waves for which this isn't true). But I want to understand how a wave function and a wave equation are supposed to behave - at least, in homogenous undamped systems.
The "wave equation" $\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2}=\frac{1}{v^2}\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial t^2}$ has a linear dispersion relation, so it's not general enough.
On  $\mathbb{R}^3$, any (friendly enough) function can be written as $$f(\vec{r},t)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}\int_\mathbb{R}\frac{\hat{f}(\vec{k},\omega)}{(2\pi)^2}\mathbb{e}^{i\left(\vec{k}\cdot\vec{r}-\omega t\right)}\mathbb{d}t\ \mathbb{d}^3\vec{k}$$
So any (friendly) function is a superposition of plane waves - though there would be multiple frequencies per wave vector.
Maybe if we admit that there is a dispersion relation $\omega=f(\vec{k})$, then we can define the following:
A wave function is the Inverse Fourier Transform of any (friendly) function of the form $\hat{g}(\vec{k},\omega)=\hat{f}(\vec{k},\omega)\delta(\omega-f(\vec{k}))$, meaning $$f(\vec{r},t)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}\frac{\hat{f}(\vec{k},f(\vec{k}))}{(2\pi)^2}\mathbb{e}^{i\left(\vec{k}\cdot\vec{r}-f(\vec{k}) t\right)}\mathbb{d}^3\vec{k}$$
While the wave equation is simply the Inverse Fourier Transform of the equation $\omega^2 \hat{f} = f(\vec{k})^2\hat{f}$. I'm not sure why you would need to square the dispersion relation, but I believe it matches the regular wave function with linear dispersion.
So what defines a wave is that it is a sum of plane waves, in a medium where frequency strictly determines wavelength. I also don't have any idea how this would apply for dampened, non homogenous, non linear cases.
Is this reasoning correct? Is there a simpler way to understand how a general dispersion relation, its associated wave equation, and the Fourier Transform are related? Because it seems like I just defined the question based on the answer I wanted

Does this answer your question? What is the general mathematical definition of wave?
